# How to Add Jquery FullCalendar in wp plugin in admin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, jquery

```
wp_register_script('moment', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )."js/moment.min.js", false, null, true);       
wp_register_script('fullcalendar', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )."js/fullcalendar.min.js", false, null, true);
        wp_enqueue_script('moment');
        wp_enqueue_script('fullcalendar');

        wp_register_style('fullcalendarcss', 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.3/fullcalendar.min.css');
        wp_register_style('fullcalendarprintcss', 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.3/fullcalendar.print.css');
        wp_enqueue_style( 'fullcalendarcss');
        wp_enqueue_style( 'fullcalendarprintcss');
```

These files which  i have registered in my plugin.this is my plugin page code .

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    



          var calendar = jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            editable: true,
            header: {
             left: 'prev,next today',
             center: 'title',
             right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            }

    }); 


  });
```

Now i am not getting any error nor getting my calendar at my page.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    

    var calendar = jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        editable: true,
        header: {
         left: 'prev,next today',
         center: 'title',
         right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        }

    }); 

});
```

Now i am not gett

Comment: What does that mean? Please improve this answer. See [answer]

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look on it:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/therich-wp-fullcalendar/

Thank you